# Need help finding an element

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting back into Selenium and ran into a bit of a snag while writing a script. 
How to I find an element like this in Selenium?

```
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default js-ajax-api-track-form-submit" data-tracking-token="$lookup;table=login;event=site">
```

I have tried a few of the common methods, but I can seem to find one that works. Any example will be extremely helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried xpath, and class name neither seemed to find the element.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?  Is there a `NoSuchElementException`?  Is nothing happening at all?  Also, as alecxe noted, is the element you are trying to find contained in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: You need to post the code that is causing problem, otherwise this is just a game of 21 questions. See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
'//*[@class="btn btn-default js-ajax-api-track-form-submit"]'
```

Should work.

Please let us know the url if it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `//input[@type='submit' and @class='btn btn-default js-ajax-api-track-form-submit']`